How to Filter Time Series Data from Isolation Forest Output Between Transitions from -1 to 1
I'm working with a time series dataset and using IsolationForest from scikit-learn to identify outliers. The output of IsolationForest gives me a column with values of 1 and -1, where 1 indicates an inlier and -1 indicates an outlier.
I need to filter my data by Isolation_forest column to extract segments where the value transitions from -1 to 1, and then continue until the value changes back to -1. Essentially, I want to capture the first instance of these segments where Isolation_forest changes from -1 to 1 and continues until the next transition to -1.
Here’s a simplified example of my DataFrame:



Time
X
Y
Z
Isolation_forest




0
12
45
67
-1


1
34
23
89
-1


2
56
78
12
1


3
23
45
67
1


4
89
12
34
1


5
45
67
89
1


6
78
23
12
-1


7
12
89
45
-1


8
34
67
78
-1


9
56
12
23
1


10
67
34
56
1



In this example, I want to extract the segment starting from the first transition to 1 at Time 2 until the next transition to -1 at Time 6. The result should look like this:



Time
X
Y
Z
Isolation_forest




2
56
78
12
1


3
23
45
67
1


4
89
12
34
1


5
45
67
89
1



I attempted to filter the DataFrame using
df_filtered = df.loc[df['Isolation_forest'] == 1]

However, this approach includes all rows where Isolation_forest is 1, rather than just the segments between transitions from -1 to 1 and back to -1.
How can I programmatically filter these segments from the DataFrame using pandas?

You can select the range between the first transition from -1 to 1 and last transition from 1 to -1, then only include the 1s.
col = df['Isolation_forest']
outlier = -1
inlier = 1
mask = between_transitions(col, outlier, inlier) & col.eq(inlier)
df[mask]

   Time   X   Y   Z  Isolation_forest
2     2  56  78  12                 1
3     3  23  45  67                 1
4     4  89  12  34                 1
5     5  45  67  89                 1

I wrote a handful of helper functions to do this:
def transitions(s, x, y):
    """Find points in s that transition from x to y."""
    return s.shift().eq(x) & s.eq(y)

def after_transition(s, x, y):
    """Find points in s where transition from x to y occurs or has occurred."""
    return transitions(s, x, y).cumsum().ge(1)

def between_transitions(s, x, y):
    """Find points in s between transitions from x to y and y to x."""
    forward = after_transition(s, x, y)
    reverse = after_transition(s[::-1], x, y)
    return forward & reverse

P.S. This is inspired by Andrej's answer, but a slightly different technique.

Try this:
m = df['Isolation_forest'].eq(-1)

df.loc[m.where(m).ffill() & m.where(m).bfill() & ~m]

Output:
   Time   X   Y   Z  Isolation_forest
2     2  56  78  12                 1
3     3  23  45  67                 1
4     4  89  12  34                 1
5     5  45  67  89                 1


print(
    df[
        df["Isolation_forest"].diff().cumsum().eq(2)
        & df["Isolation_forest"][::-1].eq(-1).cumsum().gt(0)
    ]
)

Prints:
   Time   X   Y   Z  Isolation_forest
2     2  56  78  12                 1
3     3  23  45  67                 1
4     4  89  12  34                 1
5     5  45  67  89                 1


EDIT:
With slightly different example:
    Time   X   Y   Z  Isolation_forest
0     -1  12  45  67                 1
1      0  12  45  67                -1
2      1  34  23  89                -1
3      2  56  78  12                 1
4      3  23  45  67                 1
5      4  89  12  34                 1
6      5  45  67  89                 1
7      6  78  23  12                -1
8      7  12  89  45                -1
9      8  34  67  78                -1
10     9  56  12  23                 1
11    10  67  34  56                 1
12    11  34  67  78                -1
13    12  56  12  23                 1
14    13  67  34  56                 1

tmp = df[
    df["Isolation_forest"].eq(-1).cumsum().gt(0)
    & df["Isolation_forest"][::-1].eq(-1).cumsum().gt(0)
    & df["Isolation_forest"].eq(1)
]

for _, group in tmp.groupby((tmp.index.diff() > 1).cumsum()):
    print(group)
    print()

Prints:
   Time   X   Y   Z  Isolation_forest
3     2  56  78  12                 1
4     3  23  45  67                 1
5     4  89  12  34                 1
6     5  45  67  89                 1

    Time   X   Y   Z  Isolation_forest
10     9  56  12  23                 1
11    10  67  34  56                 1


How does this work? I don't understand it reading it for the first time.

@wjandrea Difference going from -1 to 1 is 2 (and from 1 to -1 is -2, so just cumsum the differences and take 2s). But OP doesn't want the last group (because there isn't any -1) - so we count the -1 reversed and filter the 0 groups.

@AndrejKesely I don't know if I have put it clearly. It not that I don't want the last group. I only want the first group. There could be multiple groups too.

@ErshadAhamed See my edit.
